# MongoDB taking too much time while looping through cursor

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, performance, bigdata

I've been comparing my results between MySQL vs MongoDB using PHP script. I have 15 million records in MySQL database, and 15million documents with mongodb.

I want super fast access, to this data via my application which is currently coded in PHP.

Here is the code for MySQL

```
    $sql = "select * from history LIMIT 15000000";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) )
    {
        //echo $row["id"] . "<br>";
    }
```

Here is the code for MongoDB

```
    $m = new Mongo();
    $db = $m->dbname;
    $cursor = $db->history->find(array())->limit(15000000);
    foreach ($cursor as $obj)
    {
        //echo $obj["_id"] . "<br>";
    }
```

MongoDB's find statement is blazing fast, but the painful period is when cursor iterates and loops through all documents fetched, and it is taking too much time.

In comparison to this, MySQL's mysql_query() is a bit slow, but after looping through mysql_fetch_array(), the results are retrieved faster than mongodb.

Both MySQL and mongodb are taking too much time in fetching data and handing over data to application program. I don't know whether this is the correct way of benchmarking between both, or not.

Please suggest if there is any alternative method to speed up the process, or should I choose some other DBMS (SQL or NoSQL), or try it out with another programming language.

The size of data will be increased in future, therefore it is recommended that the devised process should be scalable enough for future.

Comment: There are too many variables in play here ... are the tests on identical hardware (but not the same machine)? Has the cache warmed for either? What's the structure of the data? Is this a common query that you need to iterate through 15 million records/documents (without using an index?) Have you tried adjusting the [`batchSize`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocursor.batchsize.php)? How large is a document/row?

Comment: Tests are made on same machine. Structure is not too complex, max of 8 columns come into play. Indexing has been done on both mysql and mongo end. Yes, I adjusted batch size, but mongodb has max capability of working with 4MB- 16MB limit. A row has 8 columns, not very huge data, you can say 25 characters per column

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here. What are you looking for? A technology selection question isn't a good fit for Stack Overflow. Is this a realistic scenario (fetching 15 million rows to a client)? I can't imagine it being common. Does it happen frequently? Is there enough RAM on the machine? Where are the DB files stored? Are they on a SAN? This is still too broad.

Comment: This is not a real time application, you can consider it as an offline processing behind the scenes for data. My questions is,am I doing some wrong implementation of required scenario with the code, or is there some other optimized solution in the market for that ?

Can mongodb go further beyond to get 15 million records processed faster.
 
Feel free to provide suggestions on it, how would you achieve such fast work with unlimited set of technologies ?